# Анимация при добавлении текста в TextView через append

Tags: java, android, textview

Подскажете, какие есть варианты добавление новой строки в TextView через append с анимацией? Например, с изменением alpha, побуквенным выводом и пр.?

Находил решения, которые, к сожалению, не подходят. Пример:
https://golos.io/android/@mstorm/animaciya-izmeneniya-teksta-textview